# Appium: Having a single test for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, ionic3, appium

I'm using Ionic 3 to write a small mobile app. Currently, it only builds an apk for Android. I would like to write Appium tests for it, but it seems that you cannot write one test for both platforms, Android and iOS, because the only way to select element from an Android app is via something like driver.findElementsByClassName("android.widget.Button");

What am I missing here? Are Appium tests vendor-specific, and I need two sets of tests to cover Android and iOS?

Can you actually write an Appium test that can be executed against an Android application and iOS application without any changes, except for the different capabilities?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Appium **Page Object with Page Factory** ***framework*** to write single test for Android and iOS platforms. It uses below strategy e.g. sign in button is present in both platforms then single code statement to handle it in one framework.

```
@AndroidFindBy(id = "btn_signIn")
@iOSFindBy(xpath = "//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIAButton[1]")
public MobileElement signInButton;
```

You can use following github [link](https://github.com/ThomasHansson/Appium-cross-platform-example) to see the example.